# Is there a compiler for Actionscript 3 on Windows?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I'm working on an app that will run on desktops and mobile devices. I have Flash Professional CS5.  However, I am working on a project that really just needs AS3, and dealing with the complications of integrating AS3 with Flash has already taken a fair amount of time.

There's a link that says "Free, open-source framework | Adobe Flex".  When I click on it it takes me to a page with Flash Builder 4.7 Premium for $700.  I'd rather have something free...

Comment: http://flashdevelop.org/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Adobe's Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html), [Apache's Flex SDK](http://flex.apache.org/), and [Adobe's AIR SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) include `mxmlc` compilers.  They can all be downloaded free of charge.  These compile .as code into .swf binaries.  The AIR SDK has the latest compiler from Adobe.

[flashdevelop.org](http://flashdevelop.org) is a free IDE (that downloads one of the above to compile, and sets up your environment automatically).  Similarly, [Flash Builder](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder.html) is a paid IDE from Adobe.

Take your pick.  I like to use [Adobe AIR SDK under wine on Linux](http://jcward.com/Setup+AIR+3.9+SDK+On+Ubuntu+12.04), personally.  =)